# Handle new tab downloading in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer in Express and working on a screen scraping project. I am trying to download a CSV file by clicking on dropdown option.
I am able to download the CSV file but the file is getting downloaded in a new tab and then the tab closed. When the new tab is closed the further code is not executed.
Can some please help me here. Please find below the code in Express.

```
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')  
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
})
const page = await browser.newPage()

const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
 const url = 'http://wwww.websitewithusercredential.com/login'

await page.goto(url)
await navigationPromise

//wait for UserID load
await page.waitForSelector('#userId')
await page.waitFor(1000);
await page.click('#userId')

await page.type('#userId', 'userId')

await page.waitForSelector('#loginPassword')
await page.click('#loginPassword')
await page.type('#loginPassword', 'password')

    await page.waitForSelector('form > .row > .login-form > .sign-in-btn')
await page.click('form > .row > .login-form > .sign-in-btn')
await navigationPromise;
const options = await page.$$('.histPopover > .customPopover > div > ul > li')
   options[1].click(); //This line will download the file in new tab 
                       //and closed and after this line nothing gets 
                       //executed below.
   await page.waitFor(10000)
   const backToHomePage= await page.$x("//a[contains(text(), 'Back to Homepage')]");
     console.log('Home page link    '+backToHomePage);
```

Can someone please let me know what should I do to handle this scenario. I have already tried to search for the correct solution but could not find one which can work properly.

Comment: Can you provide an example page where there is such download (if it's a public URL)? Usually I meet with this kind of download links all the time, now none of them I try opens a new tab :D Do you use any special option on `page.goto`? (I see you left it out from the example)

Comment: This is not a public URL . It is a site with user credentials. Iam not using any special opton. This is my code . I am trying to download a file which is in CSV format.

Comment: I have updated the complete code for more information.

Comment: I re-created the same scenario, but for me your script works fine: it goes on after the csv file was downloaded on new tab and closed. I reach the console.log: `Home page link    JSHandle@node` (even if it is not too useful without a `page.evaluate`). Can you specify what are the symptoms of _"nothing gets executed"_? Do you get a timeout error or the node is not found?

Comment: In my case the pupeteer stops like the processing is completed. I dont get anything printed. Please find below what Iam trying to do.

const backToHomePage= await page.$x("//a[contains(text(), 'Back to Homepage')]");

       console.log('Home page link    '+backToHomePage);
        if (backToHomePage.length > 0) {
            console.log('Back to homepage link found.')
        await backToHomePage[0].click();
        await navigationPromise
        await page.waitFor(1000);
        } else {
         console.log("Back to homepage link not present");
        }

Comment: @theDavidBarton thank you very much for your time and effort. It was my mistake. I did not notice the cron job configured somewhere in my application and it was getting restarted everytime i reached to the point of back to home page. I have changed the settings and now it is working fine. Thanks again for your time.

Can you tell me how i can change the path of the download. I tried using 
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: __dirname});    

but it is not working. The browser is chromium.

Comment:  I am glad you've found the solution. especially as I started to run out of ideas what could cause such problem in puppeteer: your script works fine 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217251/discussion-between-vinay-pandey-and-thedavidbarton).